# Is there a way to change the GIT URL for a Node application on BlueMix?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

It looks like when we cloned our `bluemix` application we lost the link the `jazzhub` GIT URL. I went to point the application to the original `JazzHub` project but I could not find the option to do so. How can I point essentially a new application to an existing `Jazzhub` project?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your Jazzhub project and click on Build&Deploy. Then you have to configure the stages for build (if needed) and deploy. When configuring the Deploy stage you can specify which Cloud Foundry application is the target of that stage, select the Application name of the Bluemix application that you want to bind. Then the first time you run the Deploy stage it will bind the Jazzhub project to the Bluemix application. I've just tried and it also shows the GIT URL of the new project within the Bluemix Dashboard.